# Will a tuple work for this example

Tags: python

I wrote a python script that pulls out a huge amount of data from a database (100,000 items). The script imports another module that retrieves the data by looping through a list of 30 parameters (e.g. parameter 1 pulls objects 1-5000, parameter 2 pulls objects 5001 - 15000, parameter 3 pulls objects 15001 - 16000 etc).

The return values get stored in a large list of 30 dictionaries, but it seems only the last dictionary is stored as the list is not immutable and it keeps getting overwritten everytime it iterates. Do I need to convert the list into a tuple as I'm iterating through the 30 parameters? Would the tuple contain 30 dictionaries with all 100,000 items? I can't test easily because it takes a large amount of time to retrieve the data so wanted to know is this will work. Here's the original code:

```
mylist = [{key 1: value 1},{key 2: value 2}...{key 30: value 30}]  
for items in mylist:
    returnlist = call.another.imported.module(**mylist)
```

after the loop completes going through all items in mylist, at this point returnlist only contains a dictionary of the database results for the last item (aka key 30: value 30) that was passed in, missing the previous 29 items. Would this tuple conversion work? I need all 30 items w/ 100K of objects stored. Can I then convert the tuple back to a list? Here's the proposed code:

```
mylist = [{key 1: value 1},{key 2: value 2}...{key 30: value 30}]  
for items in mylist:
    returnlist = call.another.imported.module(**mylist)
    returntuple = tuple(returnlist)
newlist = list[returntuple]
```

Comment: Try list comprehension, `[call.another.imported.module(**items) for items in mylist]`

Comment: Sorry, new to python.. don't understand your response.. can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because of that you didn't append anything to your tuple, but you are assigning your lists, instead you can do:

```
mylist = [{key 1: value 1},{key 2: value 2}...{key 30: value 30}]  
for items in mylist:
    returnlist = call.another.imported.module(**mylist)
    returntuple += tuple(returnlist)
newlist = list[returntuple]
```

Or as a better way do :

```
#returnlist=[] do it if you didn't initial it before  
mylist = [{key 1: value 1},{key 2: value 2}...{key 30: value 30}]  
for items in mylist:
    returnlist.append(tuple(call.another.imported.module(**mylist)))

#do stuff with returnlist
```

Comment: Excellent, appending to the tuple was what was missing! I bet this will work when I actually can try on the database tomorrow. Thank you.

Comment: There is no need here to convert from a list to a tuple, or vice versa.  The issue was that you weren't appending the results to a list or otherwise processing them, as Kasra correctly pointed out.  And FYI you can't append to a tuple, only a list.